# multiple image and click images for preview - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Multiple images Upload & preview

Currently working in multiple image upload and if i click multiple images in the preview window i need to see those images for example if i uploaded 2 images if i click 1st image and if i click 2nd image both image i need to see

In current scenario if i click one images i was able to see that image but if i click multiple images that is not working.

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjy3ad) for single image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template

```
<div class="card-body">
        <img *ngFor="let imgPreview of imgPreviews" [src]="imgPreview" >
</div>
```

and in your component .ts change this

```
imgPreviews: string[] = [];

  onClik(e) {
    this.imgPreviews.push(e.target.src);
  }
```

Now any image you click would be added in the currently displayed ones

Comment: thank you so much works like a gem but one query

there should be one small restriction

 user have to click only one time the image let say if i have 2 images user can click 2 images one time but in current scneario i can one image multiple times

Comment: check this ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aodvxv